# How do you call the AWS Lamda from AWS API Gateway in Scala?

Tags: scala, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have created an instance of AWS API Gateway for AWS Lambda.

How can I handle the HTTP methods in the Lamda function?

My sample code is:

```
    class ApiGatewayHandler extends RequestHandler[Request, ApiGatewayResponse] {

  def handleRequest(input: Request, context: Context): ApiGatewayResponse = {

    val headers = Map("x-custom-response-header" -> "my custom response header value")
    ApiGatewayResponse(200, "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
      JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMap[String, Object](headers),
      true)
  }
}
```

Request class is:

```
class Request(@BeanProperty var key1: String, @BeanProperty var key2: String, @BeanProperty var key3: String) {
  def this() = this("", "", "")
}
```

How do I handle different HTTP methods? What libraries should I use?

Answer (score 2):

AWS API Gateway enables you to pass information like the HTTP method, the request path, headers etc. to AWS Lambda using the [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html).

Once you have set this up successfully, include the libraries [**aws-lambda-java-core** and **aws-lambda-java-events**](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs) into your project.

In SBT:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.2.0",
   "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "2.2.3"
)
```

These are the official libraries from AWS for developing AWS Lambda functions in Java/Scala.

Additionally, you will need a JSON processing library, for example **[circe](https://github.com/circe/circe)**.

In SBT:

```
val circeVersion = "0.10.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser"
).map(_ % circeVersion)
```

Now you can easily adapt your Handler to use the new model:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.{APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent}
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.{Context, RequestHandler}
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.syntax._
// TODO: Import your Request class!

object Handler extends RequestHandler[APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent] {

  override def handleRequest(input: APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, context: Context): APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent = {

    def log(message: String): Unit = context.getLogger.log(message)

    log("--- Received new request ---")
    log(s"Method: '${input.getHttpMethod}'") // Example use of HTTP method
    log(s"Proxy Path: '${input.getPath}'") // Example use of request path

    val request = decode[Request](input.getBody) // Decode request using circe

    request match {
        case Right(req) => // TODO: Implement business logic
        case Left(req) => // TODO: Implement error handling
    }

    val response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent() // Example for a response
        .withStatusCode(200)
        .withHeaders(
            Map(
                "Content-Type" -> "text/raw",
                // TODO: Add your own headers
            ).asJava // Convert the Scala Map to a Java Map
        )
        .withBody("Under construction!") // Or use circe again to encode a POJO

    response // Return the response
  }
}
```

I couldn't completely test this example, so be sure to come back with any problems you might encounter.

By the way, the log messages your AWS Lambda function will produce can be found in AWS Cloudwatch.

I hope this helps.